# How to return IList<Int> of type property values from DB using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, ilist

I need to return list of ACC_INTERVAL_ID property values for specified Date from DB using NHibernate to get the available time intervals. NHibernate version is 2.1.2.4000

The AccreditationRecord:

```
public class AccreditationRecord : DomainObject
    {
        public AccreditationRecord()
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Интервал встречи
        /// </summary>
        public virtual AccreditationTimeIntervalEnum Interval { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Дата встречи
        /// </summary>
        public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Название компании
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string CompanyTitle { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Название выставки
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string ExhibitionTitle { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Комментарий аккредитируемого к форме
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

The mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Mvk.Kvc.Domain" assembly="Mvk.Kvc.Domain">

<class name="AccreditationRecord" table="KVC_ACCREDITATIONS" lazy="false" >
  <id name="ID" column="ID_ACCREDITATIONS" type="Int32" unsaved-value="-1">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>

  <property name="Date" column="ACC_DATE" type="DateTime" />
  <property name="CompanyTitle" column="COMPANYTITLE" type="AnsiString" length="512" />
  <property name="ExhibitionTitle" column="EXHIBITIONTITLE" type="AnsiString" length="512" />
  <property name="Comment" column="COMMENT" type="AnsiString" length="1000" />
  <property name="Interval" column="ACC_INTERVAL_ID" type="AccreditationTimeIntervalEnum" />
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my method in repository:

```
public virtual IList<int> GetFilledIntervals(DateTime selectedDate)
{
    DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria
        .For(typeof(AccreditationRecord));

    query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Date", selectedDate));

    query.SetProjection(Projections.Id());
    return  ??????????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With HN3:

```
public virtual IList<int> GetFilledIntervals(DateTime selectedDate)
{
    IList<int> result =
    session.QueryOver<AccreditationRecord>()    
        .Where(ar => ar.Date == selectedDate)
        .Select(c => c.Id)
        .List<int>();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual IList<int> GetFilledIntervals(DateTime selectedDate)
{
    DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria
    .For(typeof(AccreditationRecord))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Interval"));

    query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Date", selectedDate));
    return List<int>(query);
}
```